# chrome.runtime missing properties in manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to [migrate](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/) my browser extension to manifest version 3 but I am not able to access some properties from `chrome.runtime` in my service_worker. Code explains more than words I guess.

My background.js file:

```js
function call() {
    console.log({ runtime: chrome.runtime })
    chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(() => null)
}

// putting it to timeout otherwise I couldn't access the logs page
setTimeout(() => {
    call()
}, 0)
```

My manifest:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

When I open service worker page I can see

```
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry is not a function
```

The same code works with v2:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["backgroud.js"]
    }
}
```

The method I am trying to use is documented [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/) but it is clearly missing in the runtime object (with plenty of others...)

Comment: It's not implemented, see [How do I get access to all the files in the extension in Chrome Extension Manifest Version 3 (MV3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976345)