# Can't use chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry in service work with the manifest v3 Chrome Extension standard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In manifest v2, I've used [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) in the background script to list all the files within a subfolder that came with the extension to realize a specific design feature.

Now that Google is forcing me to  migrate my extension from manifest v2 standard to manifest v3, I tried to do the same feature using the [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) method but chrome would simply report this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry is not a function
```

Can anyone help with this please?
or provide an alternative method for me to list all the filenames in a specified subfolder that would be shipped within the extension?

Comment: I googled and came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66066405/chrome-runtime-missing-properties-in-manifest-v3 which linked to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65975659/how-do-i-get-access-to-all-the-files-in-the-extension-in-chrome-extension-manife/65976345#65976345 all here on stackoverflow

Comment: you had me at really sucks :p

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I've found a workaround!

For those having the same problem, one can simply choose to invoke the [chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) method in a js script that is added onto the [pupup](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/#popup) html of the chrome extension.